# Volume Ray Marching rendered always on top of the other objects

Tags: c#, sorting, unity-game-engine, shader, zbuffer

I have a really big problem that has been bothering me for so long and I can't seem to find the solution. I have downloaded this project https://github.com/brianasu/unity-ray-marching/tree/volumetric-textures (Unitypackage with my project here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27758186/ApplicationVolume.unitypackage ) , that is about volume rendering.

The problem is that, as you can see, the volume renders ALWAYS in front of everything else (try placing a cube in front of the cube with the volume). I have tried a lot of things but none seems to work.

I think it might be an issue of the shaders used. In the main Camera, a RayMarching script is attached, which contains an OnRenderImage method, which creates a new Camera (although disabled), and renders the volume.
I don't know if it is a shader issue, then, or more like a camera issue (is rendering with replaced shaders). I attach my current project for testing so you don't have to download from git, and I just want the volume (head), to appear behind the rectangles (not seen) when it's actually behind, and in front when it is, pretty much like an standard geometry, but it appears always on top...

Any help or suggestion would be GREATLY appreciated, I'm kind of desperate as anything works and I'm pretty sure it is a fairly easy issue.

The code of the shader of the Ray Marching is as follows. Should it do some kind of ZTesting to not show the fragments that are covered by any other object?

```
Shader "Hidden/Ray Marching/Ray Marching" 
{

CGINCLUDE

#include "UnityCG.cginc"
#pragma target 3.0
#pragma profileoption MaxLocalParams=1024 
#pragma profileoption NumInstructionSlots=4096
#pragma profileoption NumMathInstructionSlots=4096

struct v2f {
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float2 uv[2] : TEXCOORD0;
};

sampler3D _VolumeTex;
float4 _VolumeTex_TexelSize;

sampler2D _FrontTex;
sampler2D _BackTex;

float4 _LightDir;
float4 _LightPos;

float _Dimensions;

float _Opacity;
float4 _ClipDims;   
float4 _ClipPlane;

v2f vert( appdata_img v ) 
{
    v2f o;
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);

    o.uv[0] = v.texcoord.xy;
    o.uv[1] = v.texcoord.xy;
    #if SHADER_API_D3D9
    if (_MainTex_TexelSize.y < 0)
        o.uv[0].y = 1-o.uv[0].y;
    #endif          
    return o;
}

#define TOTAL_STEPS 128.0
#define STEP_CNT 128
#define STEP_SIZE 1 / 128.0

half4 raymarch(v2f i, float offset) 
{
    float3 frontPos = tex2D(_FrontTex, i.uv[1]).xyz;        
    float3 backPos = tex2D(_BackTex, i.uv[1]).xyz;              
    float3 dir = backPos - frontPos;
    float3 pos = frontPos;
    float4 dst = 0;
    float3 stepDist = dir * STEP_SIZE;


    for(int k = 0; k < STEP_CNT; k++)
    {
        float4 src = tex3D(_VolumeTex, pos);

        // clipping
        float border = step(1 - _ClipDims.x, pos.x);
        border *= step(pos.y, _ClipDims.y);
        border *= step(pos.z, _ClipDims.z);
        border *= step(0, dot(_ClipPlane, float4(pos - 0.5, 1)) + _ClipPlane.w);

        // Standard blending            
        src.a *= saturate(_Opacity * border);
        src.rgb *= src.a;
        dst = (1.0f - dst.a) * src + dst;

        pos += stepDist;
    }

    return 3.0F*dst;// + dst;
}

ENDCG

Subshader {

Fog { Mode off }


Pass 
{
    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma vertex vert
    #pragma fragment frag

    half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR { 

    return raymarch(i, 0); 
    }   
    ENDCG
}                   
}

Fallback off

} // shader
```

Comment: I implemented Raymarching in Unity Engine github.com/smkplus/UnityRayMarching